# Mysql and NDB are not connected

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

i am new in my mysql and i try to configure and run a cluster. i have done the installation and the config , my.cnf .
We can see the manager of cluster and the data node correct :

MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.7.13 ndb-7.5.3

2016-10-05 16:48:55 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel connected to '10.1.4.39:1186'
2016-10-05 16:48:55 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel allocated nodeid: 2

All okay but then i go check my cluster and it show that:

```
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --
ndb_mgm> show
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=2    @10.1.4.41  (mysql-5.7.13 ndb-7.5.3, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=3    @10.1.4.42  (mysql-5.7.13 ndb-7.5.3, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @10.1.4.39  (mysql-5.7.13 ndb-7.5.3)

[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from manager.mysql.cluster)
```

why the mysqld is not connected ? That output is normal ?
When i connect to mysql doesnt show the its connected to ndb as it should

[Mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVrlO.png)

and when i do show engines in mysql doesnt have it

[show engines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24hjp.png)

Please help me if you have got a similar problem or someone knows the solution of this problem or what i have done wrong, tell me about it.
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Comment: NDB is complex to set up.  Was there some requirement for NDB?  Or would simply MySQL (with InnoDB) be good enough?

Comment: @RickJames No requirement. I just have to create a cluster(mysqlcluster) of 2 machines and run some test to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start SQL server (mysqld process) manually.

Invoke mysqld with the `--initialize` option:

```
bin/mysqld --initialize
```

---

You might need to specify `--basedir` or `--datadir` options if mysqld does not see correct installation or data directories

```
bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
```

---

MySQL version prior to 5.7.6, use `mysql_install_db`